# Pandas cumsum on pivoted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, cumsum

I have a pivoted dataframe of the form.

```
      Quantity             Result            
Alpha        A    B    C        A     B     C
Order                                        
1          3.0  0.0  0.0     Best  None  None
2          0.0  6.0  4.0     None  Good  Good
3          3.0  0.0  0.0  Average  None  None
```

and I am trying to create another major column called CumulativeQty with 3 columns which I want to be the cumsum() of the corresponding 3 columns in the major column Quantity. Without individually specifying the minor columns, how would I go about it? I tried

```
p['CumulativeQty'] = p['Quantity'].cumsum(axis=1)
```

but this complains that ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1.

The desired result is

```
            CumulativeQty                     
Alpha        A    B    C      
Order                                        
1          3.0  0.0  0.0     
2          3.0  6.0  4.0     
3          6.0  6.0  4.0
```

Below is how to get the starting pivoted dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, "A", 3, "Best"], [2, "C", 4, "Good"], [2, "B", 6, "Good"], [3, "A", 3, "Average"]],
                  columns=["Order", "Alpha", "Quantity", "Result"])
p = df.pivot(index="Order", columns="Alpha")
p['Quantity'] = p['Quantity'].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
p.join(p[['Quantity']].cumsum().rename(columns=dict(Quantity='Cumsum')))

      Quantity             Result             Cumsum          
Alpha        A    B    C        A     B     C      A    B    C
Order                                                         
1          3.0  0.0  0.0     Best  None  None    3.0  0.0  0.0
2          0.0  6.0  4.0     None  Good  Good    3.0  6.0  4.0
3          3.0  0.0  0.0  Average  None  None    6.0  6.0  4.0
```

**Option 2**

```
pd.concat([
        p.Quantity, p.Result, p.Quantity.cumsum()
    ], axis=1, keys=['Quantity', 'Result', 'Cumsum'])

      Quantity             Result             Cumsum          
Alpha        A    B    C        A     B     C      A    B    C
Order                                                         
1          3.0  0.0  0.0     Best  None  None    3.0  0.0  0.0
2          0.0  6.0  4.0     None  Good  Good    3.0  6.0  4.0
3          3.0  0.0  0.0  Average  None  None    6.0  6.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is:

```
for i in sorted(df.Alpha):
    p['CumulativeQty',i] = p['Quantity',i].cumsum(axis=0)
```

please notice that i changed `axis=1` to `axis=0` because you were summing horizontally and so you were not getting your desired output.

output:

```
      Quantity             Result             CumulativeQty          
Alpha        A    B    C        A     B     C             A    B    C
Order                                                                
1          3.0  0.0  0.0     Best  None  None           3.0  0.0  0.0
2          0.0  6.0  4.0     None  Good  Good           3.0  6.0  4.0
3          3.0  0.0  0.0  Average  None  None           6.0  6.0  4.0
```

your problem was basically that you were trying to fit all `A B and C` results inside one columns. so it's basically a "MultiIndex" problem.